# Rails getting undefined method for existing field in database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, migration

So I have a field in the question table, called is_public..I migrated my database, restarted it and now when I get this error everytime I call is_public for a record in the question records.

```
undefined method `is_public' for #<Question:0x7e9aa780>
```

Any ideas to why this is happening ?

Comment: That's a strange bug. Did the migrations successfully migrate? can you reproduce the error in console? Is your model inheriting from ActiveRecord?

Comment: Is `is_public` listed when you call `question.attributes.keys` ? Is `is_public` a boolean field? If so, then use `?` at end: `is_public?`. Ps. This is not an answer, cos I dunno if you will accept it :D

Comment: @zabba: When I do question.attributes.keys, I get is_public listed. Sorry for not mentioning it before, yes is_public is a Boolean field. 

@trip: Yes, migrations work fine. I can alter the value successfully in the Rails console, it saves the data and everything...the only problem is, in the views.

Comment: When I add attr_accessor :is_public, it removes the error, but the data isn't saved after being submitted. Pretty weird...

Comment: What happens when you call is_public? (with the question mark)?

Comment: I get undefined method `is_public?' for #<Question:0x7ec9c1c8>

Comment: Please show us your `db/schema.rb` code for the `questions` table.

Comment: If you're problem appears when using views, you might want to show your view(s) and controller code.

Comment: how did you solve it? I am having this issue while running Rspec tests. this helped me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8966612/rspec-and-undefined-method-on-model

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this was the issue, but I had the same problem, and it looks like somehow my `schema.rb` file was changed, removing that column.

I manually added it back, and the error went away.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using `attr_accessible?` If so, add `:is_public` to the list.

Comment: I'm running into a similar issue; I tried your suggestion and I'm still getting the no method error. Migration was successful in that the fields are in the table. Any other suggestions? ( it seems silly to open a new question for what sounds like the exact same issue... )