# Rails new model field throwing undefined method error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I realize there are several SO questions on the subject and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5032922/rails-getting-undefined-method-for-existing-field-in-database) describes it pretty closely but wasn't accepted or followed up on.

I've added a new field 'is_ignored' to a model using a migration; the field is already in the mysql database. The field is listed in the schema.rb and has been marked attr_accessible in the model definition, but still throws an undefined method error when I try to assign a value.

Here's what I'm working with.

Migration ( works and fills fields as expected ):

```
  def self.up
    add_column :user, :is_ignored, :boolean

    User.reset_column_information
    User.find(:all).each do |p|
      p.update_attribute :is_ignored, false
    end
```

Schema (note "go to declaration" in RM takes me here as it would working fields):

```
  create_table "users", :force => true do |t|
    ...
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.boolean  "is_ignored"
  end
```

Controller:

```
  params[:selected_users].each do |id|
    @user = User.find(id)
    @user.is_ignored = false #here is where the error is being thrown
    @user.save
  end
```

I have a lot of time invested in the controller so far and would rather not blow it away and re-scaffold if I don't absolutely have to. Is there some other step in manually adding a new field to a model I might have overlooked?

**Edit:**

I've also verified that I can access this field and set a value from the rails console, and that @user is not nil in my controller when the call is executed; yet it still throws this undefined_method error.

**Second Edit:**

So this is pretty cool; a friend suggested replacing this method call like this:

```
@user.update_attribute( :is_ignored, false )
```

Which we expected to work, but didn't! It threw the same undefined method error as before...

Comment: What is the actual error message/stacktrace?

Comment: Also - are you sure you have migrated for the correct environment?

Comment: I actually answered the question below; the debugger revealed that the id object I was piping down into the do block was an array of hashes that I was treating as an array of ids...

Comment: Ah - ok... so you should probably accept your answer so we know it's solved ;)

Comment: Ah - Sorry - I jumped the gun on that then ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A friend of mine helped me figure this out, it ended up coming down to how I was getting the ID from a form:

```
<td><%= check_box_tag "selected_users[#{ignored_user.id}]" %></td>
```

What I didn't know about this was that placing something into the square brackets doesn't create an array of that object like I expected, but creates a hash of checkbox values keyed by the object placed into the square brackets. So when operated on by the controller, I was passing a hash down:

```
{'42'=>'1'}
```

Changing my code to pipe a second parameter down into the do block split this hash and allowed me to operate on the id of the selected user:

```
params[:selected_users].each do |id,value|
  @user = User.find(id)
  @user.is_ignored = false #here is where the error is being thrown
  @user.save
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have to add the field to attr_accessible since its a column backed field (active record will be able to work with the field without any additional code).  Did you try restarting your development server (re-run 'rails server')?

Comment: Indeed I have, several times but with no change in the application's behavior. I've even verified with cports that there weren't any processes listening on 3000 before restarting, all with no effect.

Comment: hmmm, are you able to log into your database and see that the column exists in the schema?  Are you able to populate the field inside of rails console?

Comment: I see the column in the database and have been able to query against it. Trying to get to it from the console but I'm having trouble even getting to the user model in the first place.

Comment: Ok, yes I see it in the database and yes I can access the is_ignored field and put a value into it from the rails console on the same environment the app is running in while debugging.

Comment: Try verifying that your @user variable isn't nil

Comment: The user variable is not nil, but that was a good suggestion; further more I can see the is_ignored field inside the user hash; yet when it hits user.is_ignored = false it still throws undefined method...

Answer (score 0):

`User` or `UserFacebookFriend`? - these seem like different models to me. You've only added the column to `User`

Comment: Oops! Forgot to change that to User before posting to SO. Fixed.