# rspec and undefined method on model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec

I'm trying to follow the railscasts on Integration Testing and am testing a password reset url. I am having a problem with NoMethodError and am not sure what is going on.

I have a user model that has a forgot_password value which is just a hash that will be emailed out.

This seems to be working

```
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :001 > u=User.find(1)
...
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :002 > u.forgot_password
 => "1280aceaf23f185a2d09a57b5534e7e3"
```

but I get the following error:

```
1) PasswordResets emails user when requesting password reset
   Failure/Error: click_button "jt"
   NoMethodError:
     undefined method `forgot_password=' for #<User:0x007ff916b03da0>
   # /Users/jt/rails-1/app/controllers/users_controller.rb:61:in `forgot_password_confirmation'
   # (eval):2:in `click_button'
```

and here is the spec:

require 'spec_helper'

```
describe "PasswordResets" do
  it "emails user when requesting password reset" do
    user=Factory(:user)
    visit log_in_path
    click_link "password"
    fill_in "email", :with => user.email
    click_button "jt"
  end
end
```

What does the the NoMethodError tell me? It looks as if from rails c, the forgot_password value exists. What am I missing?

thx

Comment: make sure you've run the rake db:test:prepare if you added fields in your migration.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Just for future searchers:

When you see a no-method error with something like "attributename=" -- but you know active-record is adding that attr_accessor to the model, you should make sure you've run:

```
rake db:test:prepare
```

After your migration. Can't say how many times this has got me!